tkinter canvas resolution of lines
I'm struggling with the resolution of lines drawn on a tkinter canvas. They always come out very jagged. I tried using tk.scale('tk', scaling', ..) but that didn't seem to make a difference. I've seen elsewhere that on Windows they use the ctypes library but that doesn't apply to me on Linux. Does anybody know how to fix that?
I'm using Arch Linux with Wayland/Sway on an XPS 17. Here's some information about the screen:
$ swaymsg -t get_outputs
Output eDP-1 'Sharp Corporation 0x1517 Unknown' (focused)
  Current mode: 3840x2400 @ 59.994 Hz
  Power: on
  Position: 0,0
  Scale factor: 2.000000
  Scale filter: nearest
  Subpixel hinting: unknown
  Transform: normal
  Workspace: 5
  Max render time: off
  Adaptive sync: disabled
  Available modes:
    3840x2400 @ 59.994 Hz
    3840x2400 @ 47.995 Hz

Here's a simple example:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class ViewCanvas(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, app):
        app.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        app.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(app, bg='white')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

        self.canvas.create_text(40, 50, text='TEXT', fill='green')
        self.canvas.create_line((10, 10, 250, 100, 300, 400, 800, 250))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tk.Tk()
    v = ViewCanvas(app)
    app.mainloop()


Thanks for your help!
